# Rack-mini-profiler gem installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack-mini-profiler

I am trying to implement a gem called rack-mini-profiler, where while running the server I got the following errors, which are because of adding configuration options in config/initializers/mini_profiler.rb as in its documentation:

```
 1. undefined method `enabled=' for #
 2. <top (required)>': undefined method `flamegraph_sample_rate=' for #<Rack::MiniProfiler::Config:0x00000002701488> (NoMethodError
```

Documentation link https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler

Would somebody help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in same situation.

These options seems to added after released rack-mini-profiler 0.1.31 (It's latest stable release).
If you want to use new options mentioned in README, so update rack-mini-profiler gem to 0.9.0.pre (It's released Dec 5, 2013).

See also https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-mini-profiler

Hope this helps.